# Postgres loop for each registry and search at another table

Tags: postgresql

First of all, sorry for my bad english.

I´m new to postgres and database syntax, I have a table called vars and at another table I have a registry from a text, a long text.

I need to search at the text, with regular expression, for each vars that I have. If I match one of the vars at the text, just return a select with Ok.

Is this possible?

Again, sorry if my english is bad.

Best regard´s.

Comment: It will help to answer question if you can include sample data that you will be searching and sample regular expressions you will be using to search that data with.  The more detail the example the better an answer you will get.

Comment: Thanks, I´m creating a better post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

Sounds like you want to make use of a stored function and the regular expression searching ability that Postgre has built in.

Read this link on searching methods http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html

I think you want something like this. Note that I didn't compile this is just my stab at it out of my head so you may need to tweak it a bit and for sure test it against your data. But hopefully it gives you the general idea.  I wrote the function below to have a single purpose, so call this function for each var value.  You might want to call this in a wrapper function that lets you pass all var values at once and loops through all var values calling the function below for each one.

```
CREATE FUNCTION search_var(i_some_text_id IN INTEGER,i_regx IN TEXT) RETURNS VARCHAR AS $$
DECLARE
    is_found VARCHAR(6) :=  'NOT OK';
BEGIN

    SELECT 'OK' INTO is_found
    FROM some_text
    WHERE some_text_id = i_some_text_id
      AND text_value ~ i_regx;

    RETURN is_found;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I own a text without spaces or line breaks, this list of variables will be used as research in this text, your believe that with this role, she will be able to provide me this? thank you